# How to print a variable directly using EJS template engine?

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I'm using Node.js with Express web framework (and EJS template engine).
When I have to print a variable I do something like:

```
<% if (value) { %>

<%= value %>

<% } %>
```

Can I do the same thing without open others brackets ? Like:

```
<% if (value) { PRINT VALUE } %>
```

Is this possible? How to print the variable?

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use `<%= value %>`?

Comment: because I, for example, would like to do something like <% if (value) { PRINT "foobar" } %>, if this condition is met, check a checkbox or something similar.

Answer (score 25):

I'm amazed to find that apparrently you can't do it, like in PHP:

```
<?php if ($value) : ?>
    <?php echo $value; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

However a slightly better solution may be to do

```
<%= (value) ? value : '' %>
```

I say this assuming that the condition may occasionally be more complex, i.e.

```
<%= (str.length > 100) ? truncate(str) : str; %>
```

Which is much nicer than

```
<% if (str.length > 100) { %>
<%= truncate(str) %>
<% } %>
```

even if it is a slightly contrived example.

I'd love to be shown a direct command to do it, as per your original question.

Comment: Or even shorter <%= value || '' %>

Comment: its simply `<%=' '%>` you can either put your key and it will print the key's value or you can put a string in quotes and it'll print that.

Answer (score 0):

There is now an `outputFunctionName` parameter that you can use. According to the [documentation](https://ejs.co/#docs):

> `outputFunctionName` Set to a string (e.g., 'echo' or 'print') for a function to print output inside scriptlet tags.

Answer (score 0):

```html
 <% console.log(posts) %>
```

NB: Make sure you define your variable in any other file you have eg app.js file...

```html
let posts = [];

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.render("home", {
        posts: posts
    });
});
```

[image: Output]

Answer (score 0):

after some struggle I found this,

```
<% if(userData.email != null){ 
   __append('email found!'); 
   or
   __append(userData.email);
}%>
```

it is working fine in my nodejs express ejs app